# Alternatives of deprecated scipy imresize() function?

Tags: python, image, resize

I used to use the scipy resize function in order to downscale an image. But as this function is deprecated in the newest version of scipy, I am looking for an alternative. PIL seems to be promising, but how can I use that for 3d images? (600,800,3) to (300,400,3)

I looked into numpy.resize, skimage, but especially for skimage, I am not sure if it works exactly like scipy's imresize() did.

Comment: Did you try openCV?

Comment: hi avin, i thought cv2 resize takes 2d array only?

Comment: I looked into cv2 (openCV), found:

import cv2
content_image = scipy.misc.imread("images/louvre.jpg")
content_image = cv2.resize(content_image, None,fx=0.5,fy=0.5)

works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639813/resizing-rgb-image-with-cv2-numpy-and-python-2-7) is one way of resizing colour images with OpenCV.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('image.png')
cv2.imshow("Original", image)
"""
The ratio is r. The new image will
have a height of 50 pixels. To determine the ratio of the new
height to the old height, we divide 50 by the old height.
"""
r = 50.0 / image.shape[0]
dim = (int(image.shape[1] * r), 50)

resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.imshow("Resized (Height) ", resized)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [official docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html), you can use `numpy.array(Image.fromarray(arr).resize())` instead.

P.S: There are also many other image functions deprecated form the `scipy.misc` module. You can check them [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/misc.html). I also quote them bellow in case the website changes:

> ```
> Deprecated functions:
> bytescale(*args, **kwds)  bytescale is deprecated! bytescale is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.
> fromimage(*args, **kwds)  fromimage is deprecated! fromimage is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0.
> imfilter(*args, **kwds)   imfilter is deprecated! imfilter is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.
> imread(*args, **kwds)     imread is deprecated! imread is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.
> imresize(*args, **kwds)   imresize is deprecated! imresize is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.3.0.
> imrotate(*args, **kwds)   imrotate is deprecated! imrotate is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.
> imsave(*args, **kwds)     imsave is deprecated! imsave is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.
> imshow(*args, **kwds)     imshow is deprecated! imshow is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.
> toimage(*args, **kwds)    toimage is deprecated! toimage is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.
> ```

Comment: Are the parameters the same? I assume `def imresize(arr, *args, **kwargs): return numpy.array(Image.fromarray(arr).resize(*args, **kwargs))` will work as a drop in replacement? I'm trying to get code working on 1.2 I don't fully understand.